# How to send/type a colon

Tags: autohotkey

I wish to send the following string to cmd:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root
```

The problem is to send the colon,

I tried

```
Send, c:Send, \xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root
```

and

```
Send, c{:}Send, \xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root
```

But they all turn out to be

```
Send, c;Send, \xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root
```

Comment: In general you should use [*SendInput*](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) rather than *Send*. To prevent translation you can use *SendRaw*. [Escape sequences](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm) might also come in handy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [escaping with the backquote](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm):

```
Send C`:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root
```

And as a hotstring example:

```
::x::`:`
```

Which replaces `x` with `:`.

Comment: Pay attention to the difference between ` (accent grave) and ' (single quote). Alternatively, you can use `{:}`